# using threads on an Atomic Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am writing code to let 4 threads build a histogram.

I have an array in main:

```
int N = 10000;
Random r = new Random();
int[] a = new int[N];

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    a[i] = Math.abs(r.nextInt() % 100);
}
```

So basically what I want to do is cycle through this array and count how many times each number appears.

So I have written my thread class, and I used `AtomicInteger` which I thought would help solve the problem of multiple threads trying to access the same index simultaneously.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class UseThread implements Runnable
{
private static int[] array;
private static AtomicInteger[] count;
private static boolean[] check;

public UseThread(int[] array, AtomicInteger[] count)
{
    this.array = array;
    this.count = count;
    this.check = new boolean[array.length];
}

public void run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (!getIndex(this.check[i]))
        {
            this.check[i] = true;
            int number = array[i];
            count[number].incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized static boolean getIndex(boolean check2)
{
    return check2;
}
```

However, this hasn't quite fixed my problem. Some of the threads are accessing the array at the same time, making the `count` array, hold a larger value than the length of the `array` array.

I think the problem is in the boolean array of checking. I have a feeling that multiple threads access the same boolean array index at the same time.

I figure it is probably a simple fix, but I am just not seeing it.

Any suggestions??

I have tried the `AtomicBoolean` array, but it has not helped. Below is the same class but with the `AtomicBoolean` array implemented.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Assign7Q3 implements Runnable
{
private static int[] array;
private static AtomicInteger[] count;
private static AtomicBoolean[] check;

public Assign7Q3(int[] array, AtomicInteger[] count)
{
    this.array = array;
    this.count = count;
    this.check = new AtomicBoolean[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < check.length; i ++)
        check[i] = new AtomicBoolean(false);
}

public void run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(this.check[i].get());
        if (!getIndex(this.check[i]))
        {
            this.check[i].set(true);
            int number = array[i];
            count[number].incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized static boolean getIndex(AtomicBoolean check2)
{
    return check2.get();
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining *the problem*?

Comment: I think the problem is in the `boolean` check array of checking. I have a feeling that multiple threads access the same `boolean` check array index at the same time. @YassinHajaj

Comment: Correct. Switch it to `AtomicBoolean`, yes?

Comment: It will help you out considerably to define your shared state as its own thread-safe class. Call it `Histogram`. Instantiate a single instance and pass that single instance to all your thread objects in the constructor. This will separate the concerns of thread-safety and the business logic of your threads. It'll be easier to conceptualise and you'll end up with a reusable histogram.

Comment: That was my original thought, So I wrote the code consisting of `AtomicBoolean`, however, the results did not change. which puzzled me. @JohnKugelman

Comment: Show how you used `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: I have edited the original post, and it now encompasses the use of the `AtomicBoolean` @Radiodef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`compareAndSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndSet-boolean-boolean-) for your `if` statement to be mutally exclusive:

```
if (this.check[i].compareAndSet(false, true))
{
    int number = array[i];
    count[number].incrementAndGet();
}
```

This both checks and sets the value atomically.

Without `compareAndSet`, there is a possibility that two threads can check the value and enter the `if` block at the same time before one has a chance to call `set(true)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realize that. Much appreciated